# What does Naoko Watanabe say in Japanese to Don West?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

In [*Lost in Space* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5232792/), episode 1x06, Don West talks to Naoko Watanabe trying to find another opportunity to make some money.

She responds in Japanese, and her father, Hiroki Watanabe. responds with a very brief

> Not enough time.

His daughter then continues to say something in Japanese, and makes it clear to Don by means of a gesture that she wishes to politely end the conversation.

As opposed to other occasions, the Japanese text in these scenes is not subtitled. As we see on other occasions, Naoko is actually fluent in English, meaning that she is deliberately trying to avoid conversation here. From the characters' facial expressions, I get a hunch that what *she* says is not as brief or polite as what her father relays<sup>1</sup>.

**What does she actually say when speaking Japanese, translated to English?**

<sup>1</sup>: The people at [TVTropes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5232792/) seem to have gotten the same impression: "Mrs. Watanabe says something about Don's offer of assistance that does not seem complimentary"

Answer (score 3):

The conversation between Don West and Hiroki and Naoko Watanabe – who is Hiroki's  wife, rather than his daughter – is as follows. The italicized text is my attempt at a translation.

> **Don:** If I brought some of that back, too, would that be worth something to somebody?
>
> **Hiroki:** Uh... Only if you could keep it from becoming contaminated.
>
> **Don:** Could you teach me?
>
> **Naoko:** 冗談でしょう？100年早いよね、お父さん？ *Is he kidding? He's way out of his depth here, don't you agree?*
>
> **Hiroki:** ... Not enough time.
>
> **Don:** Oh.
>
> **Naoko:** 邪魔、邪魔、ちょっとあっち行って。あっち行って下さ〜い。*Now go away, you're bothering us. Go away, please.*
>
> **Don:** ... Thank you.

Apparently, Naoko really doesn't think highly of Don's ability to succeed at what he's trying to learn. In addition to that, they just can't spare the time to teach him their profession, and she'd rather he leave.

Her tone here is playful, joking. It looks like she's having some fun at the expense of Don, the out-of-luck smuggler.